# Looking for a reliable replacement capacitor on pool motor

Tags: pool, electric-motor, capacitor

I'm looking to replace the capacitor on the motor that drives my pool pump. The motor just "hums" when I try and start it and nothing is caught in the impeller or binding it.

This capacitor sits on top of a Century B2854 0-F56AA40A01-24 (1.5 HP motor) Picture of this below capacitor picture.

I've attached a picture of the capacitor. I've seen plenty of similar capacitors on amazon, but I wanted to consult some experts to make sure I am getting the same ratings of my current capacitor, and getting a reliable one.

I don't know my brands or companies of electronics and I don't want to buy something that can harm the motor or will fail.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried taking that label photo to your local electrical or HVAC supply house?

Comment: Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I don’t know why this popped up but will also mention the metal cans are usually oil filled and have a very long life if not bulging. It the case is plastic the capacitor is usually electrolytic and they do have a life span and start loosing capacitance and having a harder time starting.

Answer (score 3):

this is not a shopping question but more of an identification question.
To answer your question the brand is irrelevant. The cap is 30 micro farad expresses as 30uF the voltage is 370v. Any value 370 or higher will work fine.  To get the correct style search for “C65R” then match one that lists 30uF.
Most of the time when a cap fails case bulging is visible at the top and bottom. An ohm meter can be used to see if the cap charges and discharged if your meter doesn’t have a capacitance test function.

With the power turned off short the terminals together then pull 1 of the connectors off. Now using the ohms function on your meter put the leads on the 2 terminals you are looking for the value on the meter to start climbing if the value is increasing swap the leads and now the value should be dropping if this can be observed and the case is not bulging it is probably fine. If there is no change in the value the cap is probably bad and it is time to replace it.

Answer (score 2):

The motor not starting may require more than replacing the capacitor. The date on the capacitor in the picture is 8/2013 (August 2013). I would recommend that you have the pump motor looked at by a motor repair shop. That said, if you want to try a replacement capacitor first, remove the capacitor and take it to an electrical supply store and they can sell you the correct replacement.

Comment: If the motor just hums the start switch for the start capacitor may not be working. If that is the case, the motor will not start. As I said in my aug 15 answer, it may be time for a motor rebuild.